# Gráfico em forma de ondas Canvas JS

Tags: javascript, canvas

Como posso fazer um gráfico em forma de ondas usando *Canvas* e *JS*.

O exemplo pode ajudar um pouco mais:

[image: Clique aqui para ver]

Comment: Precisa ser canvas ? ou você quer o resultado do gráfico? ai poderia usar um plugin

Comment: Que plugin seria?

Comment: Tem vários, se puder ser com plugin eu preparo uma resposta

Comment: Pode sim, sem problemas.

Answer (score 1):

Acho que pode tentar usar o Chart.js, tem um exemplo (Stacked (line)) que acho que é o que você procura:

[image: Chart.js - Stacked (line)]

Answer (score 0):

Você possui várias opções para geração de gráfico, segue alguns plugins mais populares:

[Fusion Charts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/)

[Highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/)

[Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/)

No exemplo que eu vou dar, vai ser usando Fusion charts (Pois estou mais acostumado, mas pra praticamente todos os plugins que você encontrar vão seguir a mesma lógica)

No caso não seriam 'ondas' e sim um gráfico de área.

Defina um json com o cabeçario do gráfico:

Obs: Estou deduzindo que os dados para o gráfico irão vir via PHP.

```
$json = '';
//Essa chave é fechada no segundo bloco de código da resposta
$json .= '{';
$json .= '"chart": {';
$json .= '"caption": "Gráfico de valor",';
$json .= '"subcaption": "",';
$json .= '"yaxisname": "Valor",';
$json .= '"formatnumberscale": "1",';
$json .= '"plotgradientcolor": "34495e",';
$json .= '"bgcolor": "FFFFFF",';
$json .= '"showalternatehgridcolor": "0",';
$json .= '"showplotborder": "0",';
$json .= '"showvalues": "0",';
$json .= '"labeldisplay": "WRAP",';
$json .= '"divlinecolor": "CCCCCC",';
$json .= '"suseroundedges": "1",';
$json .= '"showcanvasborder": "0",';
$json .= '"canvasborderalpha": "0",';
$json .= '"defaultnumberscale": "PB",';
$json .= '"numberscalevalue": "1024,1024",';
$json .= '"palettecolors": "34495e",';
$json .= '"showborder": "0"';
$json .= '},';
```

Depois de definir o cabeçário, você irá definir os dados e as labels para o gráfico:

```
$json .= '"data": [';
$json .= '{';
$json .= '"label": "2012",';
$json .= '"value": "43570",';
$json .= '"stepSkipped": false,';
$json .= '"appliedSmartLabel": true';
$json .= '},';
$json .= '{';
$json .= '"label": "2013",';
$json .= '"value": "55553",';
$json .= '"stepSkipped": false,';
$json .= '"appliedSmartLabel": true';
$json .= '},';
$json .= '{';
$json .= '"label": "2014",';
$json .= '"value": "68892",';
$json .= '"stepSkipped": false,';
$json .= '"appliedSmartLabel": true';
$json .= '},';
$json .= '{';
$json .= '"label": "Predicted",';
$json .= '"showlabelborder": "0",';
$json .= '"labelhalign": "left",';
$json .= '"lineposition": "0",';
$json .= '"dashed": "1",';
$json .= '"color": "#6E98AA",';
$json .= '"vline": "true",';
$json .= '"startIndex": 2';
$json .= '},';
$json .= '{';
$json .= '"label": "2015",';
$json .= '"value": "83835",';
$json .= '"stepSkipped": false,';
$json .= '"appliedSmartLabel": true';
$json .= '},';
$json .= '{';
$json .= '"label": "2016",';
$json .= '"value": "101055",';
$json .= '"stepSkipped": false,';
$json .= '"appliedSmartLabel": true';
$json .= '},';
$json .= '{';
$json .= '"label": "2016",';
$json .= '"value": "120643",';
$json .= '"stepSkipped": false,';
$json .= '"appliedSmartLabel": true';
$json .= '}';
$json .= ']';
//Esse é o fechamento da chave do primeiro bloco
$json .= '}';
```

As labels e o valor das labels pode ser trazido do banco, de um csv, outro json, desde que ele seja EXATO para o formato de gráfico que você deseja, você encontra os exemplos pra cada tipo na documentação.

E para renderizar, você precisa instanciar a classe do fusionCharts e informar o que ela precisa fazer.

```
    //Inclua a classe do FusionCharts
    include 'caminho/ate/a/classe/fusionCharts.php';
    //Printa a div que irá conter o gráfico
    echo '<div id="chart-1"></div>';
    $id = uniqid();
    //chart-1 é a id do elemento que o gráfico irá ser renderizado,  
    //$id é necessário ser uma chave única caso deseje renderizar o gráfico mais de um vez sem dar refresh na pagina   
    $Chart = new \FusionCharts("Area2D", "$id", "100%", 400, "chart-1", "json", $json);
    $Chart->render();
```

Eu não cheguei a testar, mas isso deve te devolver algo como isso:

[image: grafico]

PS: Copiei esse exemplo do próprio site da [fusionCharts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/charts/line-area-charts/) e dei um leve explicada no que fazer.

PS2: É necessário incluir as dependencias do plugin e incluir o jQuery.